How to download file from SharePoint attached to a list item using MS Graph
I need to download file from SharePoint attached to a Task item. I'm using MS Graph. I tried to search all available resources but no success so far, no advice worked so obviously I'm missing something. It's not an attachment to Outlook message, its a file attached to one of Tasks.

What I tried:
request_url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/items/{list_item_id}/attachments'

or
request_url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/items/{list_item_id}/files'

but both ways give me response: "code":"BadRequest","message":"Resource not found for the segment 'attachments' (or 'files')
I didn't find the file(s) in drives of the site either.
How can I find and download attachments to a list or list items? I cannot use "me" or "users" id's I always need to use Site IDs and List IDs because I download files across users.

As of this answer in 2019 and some follow-up comments in 2022, this is not something that Graph supports unless something has changed since then. The answer suggests using the SharePoint REST API instead.

OK, thanks for the info. You've saved me a lot of time. If you post it as the answer I'll mark it as the correct one.
